# Get a queryset with distinct entries as close as possible to a date using Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

So, I have a model that looks like this:

```
class Names(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField()

class Entries(models.Model):
  name = models.ForeignKey(Names)
  date = models.DateField()
```

The data looks something like this

```
name   |  date

name_1 |  2011-06-01
name_2 |  2011-03-01
name_3 |  2011-02-01
name_1 |  2010-06-01
name_2 |  2010-03-02
name_3 |  2010-02-01
name_4 |  2009-07-01
```

I want to query Entries with a date, and get each name record *once* where it is *less than or equal* to the date. So, I want this returned if I query with date **2011-06-01**:

```
name_1 | 2011-06-01
name_2 | 2011-03-01
name_3 | 2011-02-01
name_4 | 2009-07-01
```

My assumption is this would do the trick:

```
date = datetime(year=2011, month=06, day=01)
results = Entries.objects.filter(date__lte=date).order_by('date').distinct('name')
```

But, I keep getting duplicate name entries in there.

Any tips, friends?

Edit: The solution was provided by Gareth Rees. I had to modify it slightly, but it looks like this:

```
sql = """myapp_entries.id = (SELECT E.id from myapp_entries AS E
                             WHERE E.name_id = myapp_names.id AND
                             '"""+date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')+"""'
                             ORDER BY E.date DESC
                             LIMIT 1)'''

results = (Entries.objects
           .extra(where = [sql])
           .filter(date__lte = date)
           .order_by('name', 'date'))
```

Comment: With data (name_1, 2011-06-01), (name_1, 2011-06-02) when filtering with '2011-06-02' date, what is an expected return for you?

Comment: Gareth solved the issue but in answer to you question, the date should be less than or equal to so: **2011-06-02**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of approaches, depending on how you need the results.

(1) If you don't mind getting the results in dictionary form (rather than `Entries` objects) then you can use [`annotate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) combined with [`values`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/aggregation/#values) to group the results. In this case the query you want would be something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Min
results = (Entries.objects
           .filter(date__lte = date)
           .values('name')
           .annotate(date = Min('date'))
           .order_by('name', 'date'))
```

(2) If you need to get the results back as `Entries` objects, then you can use [`extra`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra) to pick only entries which are the earliest among all entries with the same name:

```
sql = '''id = (SELECT E.id FROM myapp_entries AS E
                WHERE E.name_id = myapp_entries.name_id
                ORDER BY E.date
                LIMIT 1)'''
results = (Entries.objects
           .extra(where = [sql])
           .filter(date__lte = date)
           .order_by('name', 'date'))
```

Comment: Gareth, you are really quite brilliant. I do, indeed, need it as a Entries object, so I went with option 2. I changed 2 things in the SQL syntax to get it to work. The first was to make the id statement less ambigous and the second was to specify a DESC order. Unfortunately, I still don't completely understand why it works. I need to think about it for a bit longer. Thanks so much.    

`myapp_entries.id = (SELECT E.id from myapp_entries AS E
                         WHERE E.name_id = myapp_names.id
                         ORDER BY E.date DESC
                         LIMIT 1)`

Comment: Can you guys please explain what approach (2) does do different or better than my solution? I am pretty sure the subselect isn't the best performance wise either…
Especially since the opener apperently didn't even try mine.

Comment: It works on MySQL. (And yes, the sub-select probably performs poorly, which is why I put option (1) first.)

Comment: Hi Florian, thanks for your help too. I did read the documentation before posting here and, actually, I am using Postgres (and Django 1.4) but, for whatever reason, I haven't been able to get the distinct() method to behave as expected. I did already try your version, as per reading the docs, but didn't have any luck not getting duplicates names (perhaps, there's something I'm still missing...)

Anyway, at this stage performance is not my number 1 priority, so I'm happy to go with Gareth's answer.

Comment: @lextoumbourou, hey I just tested my example: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/585588/ and get the following result: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/585587/ -- If you get different results please let me know, there might be a bug since distinct on is quite new…

Answer (score 0):

Try using .distinct('name__name') since you're wanting to traverse the foreign key.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried that already. No dice, baby. Thank you so much though, if you even need help moving house, let me know.   

**Entries.objects.filter(date__lte=date).order_by('date').distinct('name__name')**
> [<Entries: name_4 2009-07-01>, <Entries: name_3 2010-02-01>, <Entries: name_2 2010-03-01>, <Entries: name_1 2010-06-01>, <Entries: name_3 2011-02-01>, <Entries: name_2 2011-03-01>, <Entries: name_1 2011-06-01>]`

Answer (score 0):

you probably should read the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct

.distinct(*fields) only works on postgres and requires you to match .order_by and .distinct, eg:

```
results = Entries.objects.filter(date__lte=date).order_by('date').distinct('date')
```

So in your case it's most likely something like this:

```
results = Entries.objects.filter(date__lte=date).order_by('name', 'date').distinct('name')
```